# Twitter API - Tweet counts by cashtag

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I found in a Twitter's documentation that cashtags are allowed on Elevated access level:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query#list

My account (project) is on the Elevated level but when I try to call:

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/counts/recent?granularity=day&query=$GOOGL&start_time=2022-09-28T17:10:00Z
```

I receive the following message:

> There were errors processing your request: Reference to invalid operator 'cashtag'.
> Operator is not available in current product or product packaging. Please refer to complete available operator list at t.co/operators. (at position 1)

Did I miss anything in account config?

Could it be related to that I have product "Search Tweets: 30-Days" subscribed on Sandbox level?
Would Premium subscription give me $ operator support on /2/tweets/counts/recent endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Querying for cashtags requires an Enterprise or Academic Research level access as they allow usage of advanced operators, not just "core" operators. This means that Elevated access is not enough.

[image]
from: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/counts/introduction

The "Advanced" in the 3rd column refers to a non-core operator:
[image]
from: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/counts/integrate/build-a-query

Here is a related discussion in the official forums. Maybe the policy changes if enough people ask for it: https://twittercommunity.com/t/querying-cashtags-24-on-standard-v2-api/150604